# Shopping or buying recommendations for hardware?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask shopping/buying recommendation questions for hardware?

Comment: What shopping? Buy what? It's way too broad to fit any site.

Comment: If you are looking for hardware recommendations, we have a site for that, though they have very specific guidelines about what is an acceptable question there - read their help center and tour *before* asking a question on [hardwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 7):

If you **clearly define your requirements**, the question might be on-topic for [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com). They do have very strict requirements, please be sure to read their [help center](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and this [Meta question](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206) before asking your question. The reason for this is that without these requirements, questions are very likely to attract opinionated answers and/or spam.