# Is there a Stack Exchange site to ask "maker" type questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Do we have anything for general "maker" type questions? My question is specifically about sourcing die-cut patterns and where to obtain 3M teflon products for making mouse feet.

> Maker *(verb)*:
>
> 1. form (something) by putting parts together or combining substances;
>    construct; create.
>    *"my grandmother made a dress for me"*
>
> synonyms:    construct, build, assemble, put together, manufacture,
> produce, fabricate, create, form, fashion, model "he makes models"

It's actually more of a series of questions as I'm unfamiliar with the whole process.

- I have a die press (Cuttlebug), can it cut the type of material I need.
- Where to get custom die-cuts for the press I have (or if I need a different press).
- What software to use to make die-cut patterns for ordering.
- Where to source the appropriate 3M teflon stock.

Etc.

This type of question is generally either too broad or doesn't fit well into the traditional Stack Exchange categories.

I wasn't able to find anything related to the word "maker" when searching meta. I see that we have a Stack Exchange site for 3D printing, engineering, electrical engineering, and home improvement, but not really a place for general maker-related questions for hobbyists and tinkerers.

If we don't already have an appropriate place that I'm missing, I think a general maker Stack Exchange site would be highly appropriate. Even if some questions may also be appropriate for other, more specific Stack Exchange sites, a collection of questions and answers on the SUBJECT of making stuff, which typically aligns more with hobbyists helping other hobbyists, would be a great place to find and share ideas than would otherwise be less researched and less understood by the very nature of the author's inexperience.

Comment: We really don't do shopping questions: [Shopping or buying recommendations for hardware?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284690/shopping-or-buying-recommendations-for-hardware) What's left if you remove all of those?

Comment: I understand that shopping questions are normally out of scope. But in a maker environment we're often inexperienced about where to obtain various parts to do a thing. I know that I can source parts like circuits and capacitors from DigiKey but someone new to electronic tinkering might not. I don't know anything about sourcing 3M teflon but someone else might. Etc.

Comment: What's left is: can this die-cutter do what I want (given its rated pressure) and finding out what software do I use to make patterns.

Comment: Alternatively, someone can come along and say that they want to "make" their own mouse feet but don't know what is needed. I could come along and link/share how to go about making such a thing and reference similar questions and material answers.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to remove the shopping stuff.

Comment: @RobertLongson: If this is policy, then it's a very bad restriction. «What kind of businesses bends stainless steel tubes based on CAD models» isn't a "shopping question" in my mind. I mean, doesn't SuperUser do shopping questions all the time? Like «What kind of program can I use to accomplish task X?»

Answer (score 3):

2 and 4 are pretty much classic product recommendation questions and there's no great fit for them.

> I have a die press (Cuttlebug), can it cut type of material I need.

Might work on [Arts and Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com).

> What software to use to make die-cut patterns for ordering.

May work on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), though you might also need to check with the company that makes the patterns for supported formats.